# compare contents of Either type

Tags: haskell

is there a way to use pattern wildcards for type constructors to make this ugly code shorter:

```
eitherCompare (Left  a) (Left  b) = compare a b
eitherCompare (Left  a) (Right b) = compare a b
eitherCompare (Right a) (Left  b) = compare a b
eitherCompare (Right a) (Right b) = compare a b
```

something like (which won't compile)

```
eitherCompare :: Ord a => Either a a -> Either a a -> Ordering
eitherCompare (_  a) (_  b) = compare a b
```

or some other method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that with pattern matching, but you can still simplify your code by using a helper function:

```
eitherCompare x y = compare (fromEither x) (fromEither y)
 where fromEither (Left a) = a
       fromEither (Right a) = a
```

Comment: A simpler definition of `fromEither` is `fromEither = either id id`.

Comment: This is probably too picky to even be worth mentioning, but this is not quite equivalent to the original version (imagine one or both of `x` and `y` is `_|_` and `compare` is lazy in the corresponding argument).

Comment: @ReidBarton The original version was also strict in both arguments.

Comment: A simpler definition of `compare (fromEither x) (fromEither y)` is `(on compare fromEither) x y`, where `on` is imported from `Data.Function`

Comment: @JeremyList, the original was strict but this new version is not necessarily strict.